# Magento 2.3.3 addAttributeToFilter is_saleable attribute no longer supported

Tags: product-collection, magento2-3-3

After upgrading to Magento 2.3.3 product collections filtering with the is_saleable attribute no longer appears to work and the following error is seen in templates calling the collection :

> The "is_saleable" attribute name is invalid. Reset the name and try
>   again.

What is the correct way to filter product collections for saleable products in Magento 2.3.3?

Answer (score 3):

When I raised similar question with theme devs for Porto theme which was getting error on the line

```
->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', 1, 'left')
```

citing 2nd attribute needed to be an array or null

they sent me back a patch simply removing the call to `->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', 1, 'left')` and it seems to be working as before and shows only enabled products

go figure ...

Comment: sounds like something the porto devs would do... I guess it's a solution, but not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

can confirm this
it seems is_saleable is no attribute in 2.3.3 .. 
the question is: what function had this attribute and what action did remove it?
i have udpated to 2.3.3 on all my webshops and can not look if it was inside in 2.3.2 and before
Best regards Markus

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

> ***magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php call addIsSaleableAttributeToFilter which require array argument.***

```
->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', 1, 'left')

by

->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', ['eq' => 1], 'left')
```

Comment: Hello @Geraud issertes i am facing the same issue But does't solve problem